# Using grails remotefunction with jquery

Tags: jquery, grails

I am trying to use jQuery instead of prototype in my Grails project. When I use remote function I get "data not defined".  My understanding is that prototype would return `e` but jQuery should return `data`. My `drawGraph` action is return a JSON structure. Is this the correct usage of remotefunction using jQuery?

```
<body onload="${remoteFunction(action:'drawGraph', params:params, onComplete:'loadData(data);')}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onSuccess` with `data` and not `onComplete`.